# Who has an advantage in studying Esperanto?

Tags: culture

I'm Italian and I've been studying Esperanto for four days. I think Esperanto has a mix of words from a lot of languages. Anyway, what is the language that is most similar to Esperanto and who is most advantaged when learning Esperanto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the vocabulary it definitely helps to know a Romance or Germanic language, as that is the source of most of them. 
Anyone that knows a little of a lot of languages (from Greek "kaj" to Russian "krom", Swedish "ju... desto") has an advantage. 
The correlatives come from Slavic languages, while the accusative is present in a number of Indo-European languages. 
Here a little more on language similarity from the inimitable [Claude Piron.](http://claudepiron.free.fr/articlesenanglais/europeanorasiatic.htm)
As for my personal experience, my German, French and English knowledge have all given me a leg up in learning la lingvo internacia. After learning Esperanto, I have a hard time getting back to Spanish, so that might be the language it is the most similar to in my head.

Answer (score 5):

Definitively people speaking Romance languages like Italian, Spanish and French. Esperanto shares a lot of vocabulary with them, and in a language where grammar is so easy, vocabulary matter *a lot*.

I would also say any Western has an advantage: Esperanto is written with the Latin alphabet, shared by many of the western languages, and doesn't make use of concepts like tonality, which many Asian languages use.

Comment: So, I am Italian and I'll learn Esperanto without many difficulties?

Comment: You wouldn't have many difficulties compared to any other language no matter where you are from. But being Italian would certainly make it even easier.

Comment: That Esperanto doesn't have tones is hardly a point that makes it less easy to learn for people speaking tonal languages.